# React Native Android App deployments takes too long time as 2 hrs

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am facing an issue app deployment in android device /emulator. App takes 2 hrs to build success and deploy into device/emulator.

**react-native run-android** takes 1hr 50 mins of time.

[image]

Comment: it is normal in the future, and now it takes a long time?

Comment: Yes, it takes longer time now also. Please help me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: check your internet connection and try to restart your machine. it might help

Comment: Nope, I have tried everything. When I was working with VPN access in of my PC. Then it used to take 10 mins of time. but, When I started working directly into my PC. it started taking more than 1 hr or 2 hrs time.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27898

Comment: how long does a new empty react-native project take for you to build? can you also add your system specs (cpu, ram, etc)

Comment: Newly created app took 5 mins 35 secs of time to deploy/build. And my sys specs: 1). RAM: 16 Gb,2).System type: 64-bit OS 3).OS: windows 10.